# How to make my Jekyll convert .html.md file?

Tags: markdown, jekyll

I just installed **Jekyll** and when I run `jekyll` on a directory contains some `.html.md` file. But it didn't convert it into `.html` file. Jekyll just copied th files into `_site` directory as is.

I added `_config.yml` and added

```
markdown:        maruku
```

but it still doesn't convert Markdown into HTML.

What should I do more to make it work?

Comment: Does the file have a header specifying metadata, such as a layout or title?

Answer (score 5):

A standard mistake that I've seen with new jekyll users (and did myself) was omitting the YAML front matter in the files to be converted. Each one should start with:

```
---
layout: default
title: Page/Post Title
---
```

This assumes you have a file in your "_layouts" directory called "default.html".